# autocorrect in UISearchBar interferes when I hit didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, didselectrowatindexpath, autocorrect

I have a Searchbar that generally works.  The problem comes when I test on the iPhone, the autocorrect kicks in.  I have the search bar set that if there is text in the query bar > 4 in length,then it starts putting things into the searchResults array. If there is a suggestion from autocorrect and I ignore it and select something from the array, the app crashes.  I traced the error to the fact that the autocorrected word is being selected before the row selection (but both get done), so the searchResults array I thought I was accessing is no longer valid.

For instance, I put in "demp" into the search bar. Autocorrect suggests "demo".  Meanwhile, the search returns a bunch of results with "dempster" in it.  I select the first.  As I do this, the search re-searches under "demo" and clears the original array (keep in mind I look to a server for the searches so the array has not re-filled).  Then the didSelectRowAtIndexRow method triggers and there's nothing in the array and it crashes.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I had the same problem. I would say this is a bug in UISearchBar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you are using a search bar there should be no autocorrection, people want to find what they're looking for, not what some dictionary tells them to find. Simply set

```
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

and problem will be solved.

Comment: I don't agree that there shouldn't be autocorrection. If it weren't so intrusive as it is in iOS, it would be useful.